# Spring Data Jpa Query dsl with fetch join

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

Is it possible to specify Join Fetch when using QueryDsl and Spring Data Repository?

Comment: Here is the spring documentation explaining what to do: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph

Comment: Yes, thanks, but I wanted to find the way how to do it without annotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no keyword in Spring Data JPA to trigger a fetch.
But you can write a [Custom Repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) and implement a query using Querydsl there.

Comment: It's possible to use Query annotation, and specify fetch join there.
But when I implement QueryDslPredicateExecutor to my repository, I can't mix it with Query annotation.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` can be used to perform queries only using Querydsl Predicates (where you can't use `fetch()`). For instance: `Predicate isOld = person.age.gt(65); repository.findAll(isOld);`